# I'm having "could not find driver" error even if my pdo_pgsql extension is enabled in php.ini

Tags: php, docker, symfony

i'm struggling hard learning symfony, I've got a problem with my project and I can't figure where this comes from. I can't make Entities or anything because of a "missing driver" even if I enabled it in php.ini (I made sure that was the good php.ini with php -i).

Do any of you have any clue ? I can figure anything out, I'm using docker, do you think that might be the problem ?

My php version is 8.1
Many many thanks to anyone who's reading this.

[The error i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxSL6.png)

And here is my `docker-compose.yml` as suggested by Álvaro González

```
version: '3'
services:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-13}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-app}
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-ChangeMe}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-symfony}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###

volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  db-data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Comment: Did you also install the extension and restarted apache? In `/etc/php/your_php_version/mods-available` (Not sure if this the same in Docker) you can see what mods are installed

Comment: What [exact Docker setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/docker.html) are you using?

Comment: Additionally, you run `php -i` from command-line but you're running Symfony through a web server. PHP settings don't need to be the same.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm not even sure to understand your question... I'm using Docker Desktop, are you talking about that or my docker-compose.yml ? Sorry, I'm quite ashamed but I'm a true beginner

Comment: Docker is a just a generic tool. What extensions are available for PHP totally depend on how the container is set up. Are you using someone else's Docker bundle or creating your own from scratch? (Yes, if you're using `docker-compose.yml`, sharing it can definitively help.)

Comment: I'm following the book "Symfony 6 the fast track, so I "simply" installed docker desktop, created the project with "symfony new guestbook --version=6.0 --php=8.1 --webapp --docker".. I'm editing my post with the .yml

Comment: you  should install php-pdo extension

Answer (score 0):

you can install php extension like below

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install php-pdo 
RUN docker-php-ext-install php-pqsql
```

run together

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install php-pdo php-pqsql
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm sure it's the answer to my problem beacause as I think I understand it, my local php.ini is not seen by docker. But I don't even know how to run these commands.. I'm on windows and it says "/bin/sh: RUN: not found" ..